# Create Aggregate Table from binary columns on SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, pivot-table

*Table1*

| customerid | jan21 | feb21 | mar21 | apr21 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 124 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 125 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 126 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

i have a table as above and I would like to create another table like this:

*Table2*

| month | jan21 | feb21 | mar21 | apr21 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| jan21 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| feb21 | - | 2 | 0 | 2 |
| mar21 | - | - | 1 | 2 |
| apr21 | - | - | - | 4 |

Basically, I would like to count how many customers are active in each month on condition that they are active in the given month.

I left empty for the left side of the table since it will be the symmetrical of the right side but if someone may come with a solution filled both sides of the table, it is still more than welcome.

I do it with lots of subqueries and WHERE conditions and I sum each month by changing the where condition for each month every time. However, it is very time consuming and I wonder if there is a one time SQL query to do this task.

By the way, I am working on POSTGRESQL.

Here is my query. I also create *table1* within the query as well.

I change the `jan21 = 1` for each month

```
select 
sum(jan21) as jan21,
sum(feb21) as feb21,
sum(mar21) as mar21,
sum(apr21) as apr21 

from(
select customerid, 
sum(jan21) as jan21,
sum(feb21) as feb21,
sum(mar21) as mar21,
sum(apr21) as apr21 
from (
with orders as (
select customerid, to_char(orderdate, 'YYYYMM') as orderdate
from ordertable
group by customerid, orderdate
    )
select distinct customerid,
    case 
    when orderdate = '202101' then 1 else 0 end as jan21,
    case 
    when orderdate = '202102' then 1 else 0 end as feb21,
    case 
    when orderdate = '202103' then 1 else 0 end as mar21,
    case 
    when orderdate = '202104' then 1 else 0 end as apr21        
from orders
) t1 group by customerid
) t25
where jan21 = 1
```

Comment: Can you share your coding attempt at this problem? Maybe it could be a good starting point for an improved solution.

Comment: I added my work @lemon

Comment: Should this be specific for just jan21, feb21, mar21, apr21 or is your end query intended to be generic?

Comment: in the real data i have 3 years. so i would like to do it for all months in the dataset @lemon